Why is calling Dispose() in finalizer still problematic when Dispose() is idempotent?
In my understanding:

Dispose() is idempotent. Calling it multiple times is fine, no exception will be thrown.
The order in which finalizers are called is indeterministic.

I still don't understand why calling idempotent Dispose() in finalizers is problematic because of indeterministic order of finalizer call. What am I missing here?
A trivial example that does not follow dispose pattern. It is only for illustration.
public class TrivialExample
{
    private readonly DisposableThing dt;
    public TrivialExample()
    {
        dt = new();
    }

    ~TrivialExample()
    {
        dt.Dispose();
    }
}

public class DisposableThing : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // release resources
    }
}


A side note: to make sure it's clear: "Dispose() is idempotent" - it's actually your responsibilty to implement it in such way (it's not guaranteed to be so automatically by the language).

Why do you think it is wrong to call Dispose in the finalyzer ? According to this it is actually recommended to invoke Dispose from the finalyzer , but MS recommends to add another layer with a boolean (Dispose(bool disposing)). See that post for more info.

I meant releasing the owned managed resources in finalizer.

This is because Dispose cleans up the managed resources, and that could have been already done by the garbage collector.
If the finalizer is being called, there are no more references to the DisposableThing instance, i.e. it's unreachable and eligible for garbage collection. Then the managed resources it was holding in the fields are unreachable, too, and as such could be already cleaned up by the garbage collector. If that happens, and you call Dispose in the finalizer, it will do the clean-up again.
The best practice for implementing Dispose differs from your example:
bool disposed = false;

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
  if (disposed) return;

  if (disposing) {
    // Clean up managed resources
  }

  // Clean up unmanaged resources that garbage collector cannot delete

  disposed = true;
}

public void Dispose() {
  Dispose(true);
  GC.SuppressFinalize(this);  // Tell garbage collector that it doesn't need to call finalizer after disposing
}

~DisposableThing() {
  Dispose(false);
}

This way you can avoid trying to clean up the managed resources in a finalizer.
EDIT: the GC can clean up the DisposableThing before the TrivialExample, as pointed out in this answer:

Certain references are "known roots". When a collection happens the known roots are traced. That is, all known roots are alive, and everything that something alive refers to is also alive, transitively. Everything else is dead, and eligable for reclamation.

Something that a dead object refers to isn't considered alive.
But as the OP's experiment (please see the comments) shows, it won't destroy the DisposableThing completely (destroy and clean up are different things). However, you still shouldn't call Dispose in finalizers, as it could deal with the resources held by DisposableThing, which have already been cleaned up. In your trivial example, this is probably acceptable until DisposableThing is modified to become something more than just a demo class.

What will happen when GC attempts to dispose objects that have been disposed?

If you try to reach an object that was deleted by the garbage collector, you will get null, and if you try to clean it up (i.e. call its Dispose, set its fields to null etc), a NullReferenceException will be thrown.

It is interesting to simulate it. I run for(int i=0;i<10_000_000;++i){_ = new TrivialExample(); GC.Collect();} but I cannot get the exception. Any idea to increase the chance?

Yes, that's interesting. I will try to find out the reason, but not today

@SNBS "If you try to reach an object that was deleted by the garbage collector, you will get null" that is incorrect. Those fields are still there, the GC does not set them to null, just the order of finalizers running is non-deterministic, so you may be accessing an object that has an invalid state (expects something to be not disposed but actually is)

See eg this fiddle which proves that GC does not set nulls after running a finalizer. https://dotnetfiddle.net/CqbZYN

@Charlieface That's because the GC doesn't destroy objects immediately after running the finalizer

It doesn't "destroy" objects at all. That's just not how GC works, it's a mark-sweep collector. So it marks all objects that have roots, and sweeps the rest (by compacting the heap over them). Anything which is finalizable is itself rooted, so anything it has access to will not be collected. Those finalizable objects go on the finalizer queue, and after it runs they can then be swept as normal like anything else, along with anything they themselves are the only root for. So null doesn't come into it: GC does not go around setting things to null, it just sweeps the whole lot in the garbage.

@Charlieface It can finalize DisposableObject before TrivialExample, as proven in this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/9sdQix

True, the finallizers can run in any order, but the object references themselves are still there until swept after those finalizers are run. You wouldn't want to touch another disposable object in case its state is messed up, other than to dispose it, but other objects should work fine.

@Charlieface Yes, that's what I'm talking about. You wouldn't want to dispose a disposed object, because this could require accessing its fields, which are already messed up.

@DG Updated my answer, please take a look

You are making a whole bunch of very arbitrary assumptions:

Dispose() is idempotent

It is if you write it to be so, but it doesn't have to be. Also consider that part of disposing should be releasing managed handles to managed objects (ie, setting those fields to null) after disposing them. Calling that twice will crash with a null reference exception, unless you handle that case -- which you most definitely did not in your "good enough" example.

why calling idempotent Dispose() in finalizers is problematic

You're assuming it's not. It's generally fine, but because you write your own disposables, there will be classes that implement it wrong because they think they know better, and it will break the code of people who use it as it should be used.
As an example, you can multiple-dispose of every .Net stream class, which is very important because people use them wrong and always multiple-dispose them in nested streams.
Another reason for the generally accepted dispose pattern is inheritance. Having a virtual Dispose function will allow subclasses to also dispose their data, while your "good enough" example won't.
Edit: you're also missing a way to skip making your class eligible for finalizing (which is what the normal dispose pattern does for you). That means that your object is extremely performance intensive to clean up -- remember that finalizable objects have to be moved to a special finalizing queue before being garbage collected, which involves a full thread freeze of your application to run.

Could elaborate more why we should not release managed resources in finalizer? If it is because the finalizer call is at non-deterministic order, what will happen if GC attempts to finalize an object that has been finalized.

Please read my answer again, I never said you shouldn't "release" (?) managed resources in the finalizer. In fact I didn't mention the finalizer at all, I'm talking about the Dispose function. Also what does "what will happen if GC attempts to finalize an object that has been finalized" even mean? Are you trying to say Dispose? You can't finalize an object, only the GC can do it, and only once. It has nothing to do with any non-deterministic order (of what?) or anything.

As far as I knew from reading, finalizer is called by a dedicate thread at non-deterministic order from a finalizer queue. Because of this, releasing managed resources in finalizer is considered problematic, the owned managed resources may have been finalized before the owning finalizer is executed. So what will happen when we invoke Dispose() (in the finalizer) on the owned managed resource that has been finalized by coincidence?

"the owned managed resources may have been finalized before the owning finalizer is executed" -- again, you're confusing (I hope?) disposing and finalizing. Only the GC can finalize an object, and it won't encounter any such problems. Or maybe you don't understand the word non-deterministic? It doesn't mean "at random" or "whenever the GC feels like", if that's what you think.
